# How to anchor the booking panel in the footer

Tags: html, css

I have this website [www.mydubaitrip.com](http://www.mydubaitrip.com) and you can see that the booking panel is floating on the left side. What I want is to fix it at the edge of the booking panel. How can I achieve this?

I already put in an absolute position but it is not working.

Update:

Please note that I have a javascript function that automatically re-size the banner image width and height then automatically place the footer based on the new banner image height.

Comment: Where you need the booking panel to be placed? on the right or center?

Comment: you can add css property `left` or `right` to your class `.bookDetail` where you used `relative` positioning

Comment: I want to add directly at the edge of the footer. wherein when I click the book direct. book now title the details will fadein/fadeout and the book now part will show like a popup in the footer page.

Answer (score 4):

Remove margin  and jist type

```
margin: 100px 0 0 0;
```

Comment: Just saying. It's generally a bad idea to have both position and margin on the same thing. If margin doesn't work, position should be used, but never both at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the `margin: 100px 0 0 56px;` on `.bookPanel`.

Then, with the position still set to "relative", do `top: 110px;`

Answer (score 0):

Remove left margin from `.bookPanel`, make it like this `margin: 100px 0 0 0;`

```
.bookPanel {
display: inline;
float: left;
margin: 0;
margin: 100px 0 0 0; 
position: relative;
width: 264px;
z-index: 1;
}
```

If you want to adjust the top position you can reduce the top margin value which is now `100px`